# asp mvc 3 radio buttons scenario

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have

```
public class Version
{
    public bool LeftChecked {get; set;}
    public bool RightChecked {get; set;}

    //some other properties
}

List<Version> versions = ...
```

Now in a view I want to have table with rows corresponding to `versions` list items and two columns of radio buttons: one column in one group and the other in another (so that only one button in each column could be selected). The tricky part is how do I map `LeftChecked` and `RightChecked` properties to these radio buttons so that binding happens correctly?

**Edit**
I tried as suggested in the answer, but that way html produced looks like this:

```
<tr>
    <td>        
        <input id="Versions_0__LeftChecked" name="Versions[0].LeftChecked" type="radio" value="1" />    
    </td>    
    <td>    
        <input id="Versions_0__RightChecked" name="Versions[0].RightChecked" type="radio" value="1" />    
    </td>    
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>    
        <input id="Versions_1__LeftChecked" name="Versions[1].LeftChecked" type="radio" value="1" />
    </td>
    <td>
        <input id="Versions_1__RightChecked" name="Versions[1].RightChecked" type="radio" value="1" />
    </td>
</tr>
```

Which is not ok, since same column `name` attribute should be the same. Besides it didn't seem to bind to my C# class. Well, javascript approach did the job quickly and nicely...

Answer (score 4):

You should be able to iterate through the collection of versions in the view and use Html.CheckboxFor helper to create the checkboxes. If you use the syntax below, you will get the proper binding when you post the form.

```
...other form fields

@for (int i  = 0; i < Model.Versions.Count; i++)
{
    <tr>
       <td>
          <label>Left</label>
          @Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x.Versions[i].LeftChecked)
       </td>
       <td>
          <label>Right</label>
          @Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x.Versions[i].RightChecked)
       </td>
    ... other properties
    </tr>
}
```

There is a good article by haacked explaining the basics
http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx